# DataGrid Cells Rows

Tags: c#, mysql, update

Привет есть код с WindowsForm

```
datagridview.Rows[2].Cells[3]
```

это значение получение и 2 строки  и 3 ячейки.
Мне надо также но только на WPF.
wpf есть DataGrid но у него нет

```
Rows[2].Cells[3]
```

как это организовать.
планируется использовать для обновления данных в базу SQL при изменении их в окне

```
 MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("update TV set 
model=@model,price=@price,count=@count,description=@desk where id=@id", sql);

    for(int i=0;i<=кол-воколонок;i++)
    {
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model",Тутполучаемзначениеячейки);
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price",Тутполучаемзначениеячейки);
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count",Тутполучаемзначениеячейки);
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desk",Тутполучаемзначениеячейки);
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",Тутполучаемзначениеячейки);
    }
```

Так вот вопрос подскажите как получить значение ячеек и строк.